# Is it allowed to say "Thank you" as comment in this site?

Tags: discussion, comments, flagging

In other sites of stack exchange, only saying "Thank you", "+1", "Thanks" in comment is not allowed and in Stackoverflow, [moderators tell](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged) to flag them as 
"too chatty".

My question is, is there any different rule in this site?

As like stackoverflow, I flagged [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25247/unintentionally-breaking-fast/25249#comment43948_25249) comment as "too chatty" and moderators declined me:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I declined that flag because I didn't consider that particular comment as "too chatty". "Not constructive" could have had it removed.

Like SO such comments are inappropriate here as well.

I have removed it now.

Comment: but here it should be flagged as "Not constructive" instead of "too chatty", right?

Comment: To me "Not constructive" seems more appropriate. With this meta discussion onwards, unless something else is proposed, "Not constructive" should preferably be used.

Comment: Make sure that all other mods are aware of it, otherwise we, the general people would be the victim again and again!

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244203/132874

Comment: For what it's worth, I probably would've accepted either "too chatty" or "not constructive" for that one; they can be almost synonymous sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to vary:

1. If an answer is far above average quality; I tend to add a comment saying why briefly; and not just '+1'.
2. If an infrequent or low-rep user says 'thanks!'; I tend to answer 'you're welcome' to be encouraging.
3. If an answer is useful, but I want additional clarification; I say 'thanks' or 'hello' or 'salaam'; and then go on to ask my clarifying question; I just don't say '+1' or 'thanks'.
4. Sometimes the comment is just a comment with no decorating civilities.